# How can i read a voice input in a dialog? QiChat

Tags: nao-robot

There's some way that i can possibly read a voice recognition from the dialog in nao ?

**For example:**

```
proposal: What is your name
    u1:(John Doe) ["Hey John Doe, how are you doing"]
    u1:(anything) ["Sorry, i cant hear you, please repeat"] ^previousProposal
```

What i want is, how can i set the part (John Doe) to a dynamic input given by the user. There's some variable that i can create or a predefined variable for inputs by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that using $.

Here are some example from this [documentation](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/dialog/aldialog_syntax_cheat_sheet.html)

Input selection as variable:

```
u:(my name is _[david robert]) your name is $1
```

Assign a variable:

```
u:(my name is david) i store your name $name=david
```

Condition

```
u:(is my name david) [“$name==david yes” “no it is $name”]
```

Comment: I get it, thanks. But, i think that the NAO is desconfigured, because the NAO don't recognize my voice.